# WebSocket response 502

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, openshift

On OpenShift which is supposed to support websockets, using the following socket.io code I get this response:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

In logs, I can see this:

> warn: websocket connection invalid

Sockets then fallback to xhr-polling.
I think I once had it working, but don't know what did I change that could break it.

Or, could it be that openshift would stop supporting websockets after latest upgrades?

The code (node.js server, socket.io)

```
var server = require('http').createServer(self.app);

server.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function() {
     console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...', Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.configure(function () { 
    io.set("polling duration", 120); 
    io.set("heartbeat timeout", 120);
    io.set("close timeout", 120);
});            

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        socket.emit('message', data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
     });
});
```

Client code:

```
<script>    
    var socket = io.connect('http://xy-app.rhcloud.com');

    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        $("#messages").prepend("<p>" + data.content + "</p>");
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like You've configured your server in a wrong way by setting those configuration properties to values which you probably don't know. Have you read documentation? Do you know what is `polling duration`, `heartbeat timeout` and `close timeout`? Probably you've assigned incorrect values to these. You might want to do it like this and this would work:

```
io.configure(function () { 
io.set("polling duration", 30);
io.set("heartbeat timeout", 120);
io.set("heartbeat interval", 25);
io.set("close timeout", 120);
```

});

Comment: Well, I'd think these values are related to polling transfer only. Also, the only difference between your and mine configuration I can see is that I have polling duration set to 120 instead of 30. Thanks for suggestion though, will try it later and let you know.

Comment: Its not about setting it to 30 or 60 seconds, I just tried to show you that polling duration and heartbeat interval should be less than heartbeat timeout.

Comment: I've now set this exact configuration but it didn't help, still falling back to polling with the "websocket connection invalid".

Comment: Tried to use port 8000 as I got to some article pointing to it, now I get 'info: handshake authorized' followed by 'debug: destroying non-socket.io upgrade', falling back to polling again.